# post_parent is 0 when uploading new files

Tags: posts, uploads, attachments

I have a custom-type post I'm trying to attach some `audio/wav` files to using the wp-admin UI.

When I upload the new files using the `Add Media` popup those get saved and embedded into the post just fine, but in the database those attachment-posts have `parent_post` set to 0.

It records the `post_date` and `post_author` correctly, but not the `post_parent`.

What is the reason for that behavior and how can I fix it?

**Update** ok so this only happens to the posts with custom post-type. When I upload the same audio file to the normal post it gets attached properly. If I try disabling the plugins it will remove that custom post type I'm working with and I won't be able to test.

**Update2** this happens during the upload process. Here's the `var_dump($_REQUEST);` output from [`wp-admin/async-upload.php`](https://core.trac.wordpress.org/browser/tags/4.1/src/wp-admin/async-upload.php) when uploading an attachment to the regular post:

```
array(4) {
  ["name"]=>
  string(42) "my_file.wav"
  ["action"]=>
  string(17) "upload-attachment"
  ["_wpnonce"]=>
  string(10) "457d8c9ee7"
  ["post_id"]=>
  string(4) "1234"
}
```

The `post_id` key is missing when I'm uploading an attachment to the custom post.

Comment: Does this happen with a vanilla WordPress installation with the default theme and no plugins?

Comment: Thanks for the question, no, I should've mentioned this is a working Wordpress site with plugins. I will try to disable them all and see what happens

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason was the `post_id` key simply missing from the upload query.

It was there for the normal posts, but was being omitted in the custom-post-type uploads.
No idea why. The issue had something to do with the javascript uploader settings.

So I've asked another question regarding the `pluploader` [here](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/176766/post-id-missing-from-the-wp-admin-file-upload-request/) and have managed to [find the solution](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/176767/63414) myself.

I do not know why was the `post_id` being excluded, but at least it works now.